# Safe way to upgrade old project to VS2017

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2017

We have a critical legacy app that is currently in `VS2008`, targeting `.Net 3.5`.  I would love bring it up to date with the latest `Visual Studio (VS2017)` and `.Net (4.6)`, but for important reasons, we cannot risk any subtle changes this one critical legacy app.  It's a big, complicated monster.
And yet, we still need to do minor maintenance on it (code changes), so we'd very much like to use the latest tools `(VS2017)`.  Soooo... if we upgrade that `.Net` solution from `VS2008` to `VS2017` to get the latest editor, etc. **can we ensure there are no subtle side effects from that upgrade**?  **We will keep the target version set to .Net 3.5**, but my manager is concerned some other things may also change (something about the toolset used for building?).  Of course there are good reasons to bring everything up to the latest version, but just accept as a given that for important business/legal reasons, we cannot afford to risk any subtle changes to the final compiled product, other than maintenance code changes.  Thoughts?

Comment: "Upgrade" is a risk of itself. So when you stated "we cannot risk any subtle changes", your question is no longer answerable. Period.

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear enough in the question.  What I need to know is whether we can upgrade to VS2017, as a work environment, without impacting the compiled product.   This assumes we leave the target version as it was (.net 3.5).

Comment: We have the same problem... multitudes of visual studio 2008 and 2010 solutions with fear of upgrading versions when making subtle changes to code on critical legacy apps that have limited/no unit code wrote for them outside of our CI/CD pipeline. 

Thanks for the solution @WayneS. I'll slowly look at promoting these projects as I come across them and debunk the advise I've been told that we cannot upgrade old projects. (With suitable testing of course)

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer I was looking for.

There are two flags in the project file (*.csproj) which control how the code is built:

- **ToolsVersion** –  Determines the actual tools used to compile/build the project, which can be the tools deployed with older versions of .Net and Visual Studio, or newer tools
- **TargetFrameworkVersion** – Determines which version of the .Net framework is used (older or newer)

These are set at the project level, and are independent of the version of Visual Studio used for editing.  In our case, management wanted to stay with the older tools and target framework to minimize risk, so we can control that simply by leaving these flags at their original values.  I tried upgrading the solution to VS2017, and these project values remain unchanged, so we should be good to go with VS2017.

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" ...>
. . .
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v3.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

Ref:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-toolset-toolsversion